# What does `suppressed_by_user` mean when using Google One Tap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-authentication

I am trying to get the one tap to appear when the user clocks sign in, The below code works just fine when It runs as soon as the page loads but if I try to get it run on click then I get the error `suppressed_by_user` error I don't have an advert blocking plugin running and I don't know what `suppressed_by_user` could mean?

[docs here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/reference/js-reference#PromptMomentNotification) detail the error but don't explain what caused it or how to fix it.

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
... 
  const signin = () => {
    const handleCredentialResponse = (response: any) => {
      const credential = response.credential;
      const getDetails = async () => {
        const params = new window.URLSearchParams({ credential });
        const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/google?${params}`;
        const response = await fetch(url, { method: "GET" });
        const data = await response.json();
        setLoggedIn(true);
        setState({ ...state, participant: data.participant });
      };
      getDetails();
    };
    if (state && state.participant && state.participant.id) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
    } else {
      const client_id = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
      const callback = handleCredentialResponse;
      const auto_select = false;
      const cancel_on_tap_outside = false;
      google.accounts.id.initialize({ client_id, callback, auto_select, cancel_on_tap_outside });
      google.accounts.id.prompt((notification: any) => {
        console.log(notification); // rl {g: "display", h: false, j: "suppressed_by_user"}
        console.log(notification.getNotDisplayedReason()); // suppressed_by_user
      });
    }
  };
...
<div className="center--main-join" onClick={signin}>Sign in or Join</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means the user has manually closed the One Tap prompt before, which triggered the Cool Down feature (as documented at: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/features#exponential_cooldown).

During the cool-down period, One Tap prompt is suppressed.

Comment: So if the user accidently without thinking of the consequences (and quite often the user has no knowledge of what will happen) manually closes the one tap prompt he is effectively banned from signing in until the cool down period has ended? This seems incredibly draconian and is potentially a deal breaker for "one tap" or am I misinterpreting this "feature"?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/integrate says:

"You are recommended to use both One Tap and the Sign in with Google button on your website. Due to exponential cool-down, One Tap may not be displayed every time. [...] A successful sign in using the Sign In with Google button will clear the One Tap cool-down status so that One Tap can display for the next login. Other button flows from Google cannot clear the One Tap cool-down statuses, since they are in different JavaScript binaries."

I found this behavior extremely surprising, but I guess there's a way to sign in.