# How to handle the Sign In With Google popover cooldown when it has been closed?

Tags: google-oauth, sign-in-with-google

We're developing a desktop application, the requirements of which are that the user must receive a Google token from a successful authentication first before accessing the application. The application is about ready to go live but I have some concerns about the new Sign In With Google authorization flow.

We're using the popover flow and the big issue for us is that if the user clicks the X on the popover there's now no way to sign in anymore during a cooldown period. This seems like a strange design. I myself have accidentally clicked it when doing some developer testing and I have to wait an hour or so to get it back and log in. From what I read, if I accidentally dismiss it twice in a row the timeout increases the next time.

It is a requirement of the client's that we allow the user to sign in with Google but I feel like it's untenable to tell the client when they come to us that their users won't be able to use the application for at least an hour whenever they click that X. There has to be something I'm missing about this, right? There's another way to do this without that risk of lost productivity for a locked-out user?

Appreciate any help!

************** EDIT **************

I just want to re-iterate what a huge problem this is for us. I grabbed the latest branch of code so I could see a change one of my UI guys made to the application. I clicked the log in button but for whatever reason decided I wanted to close the window and restart the login. I reflexively closed the Google sign in popover before closing the tab. Now I can't view my developer's changes for 2 hours. This functionality seems so bizarre and unnecessary, I still think I must be missing some key information on this to make it better. Even if I could somehow reset that cooldown manually after logging into my account, that's at least something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my never-ending need to solve this problem I searched again for answer and this time I *did* find an answer. This article here has various methods people are using to fix this issue. The one I used that worked best for me was to delete the `g_state` cookie. I thought I had already tried deleting all cookies, but apparently not, because this did work for me.

[Google One tap sign-in UI not displayed after clicking the close button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281579/google-one-tap-sign-in-ui-not-displayed-after-clicking-the-close-button)