# FedCM Migration: Google One tap sign-in UI not displayed after clicking the close button

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to get the google one tap button to appear again after the user has previously clicked close button. I am calling the javascript function google.accounts.id.prompt() to try to get the button to appear. I believe the problem is related to exponential cooldown which is used to avoid showing the prompt too much to the user. In my case, I would like the prompt to appear when the user clicks the sign in button, so this cooldown wouldn't be needed.

Previously deleting the cookie worked:

[Google One tap sign-in UI not displayed after clicking the close button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281579/google-one-tap-sign-in-ui-not-displayed-after-clicking-the-close-button)

However, due to chrome third-party cookie deprecation (starts Q1 2024), I believe this method no longer works and is recommended to not use those suggested functions in this migration guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/fedcm-migration

Here is my simplified code:

```
function buttonClickHandler(){
    google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
        if(notification["g"])==="skipped"){
            console.log("Pop Up Closed!") 
        }
    })
}
```

Everything works as expected, except when I click my sign in button after the prompt has already been closed, then the prompt doesn't appear and I immediately get the notification with key "g" set to "skipped".

Answer (score 0):

If users closes the One Tap prompt, it enters the cooldown period. When FedCM is enabled (it looks like that is your case), the only way to show One Tap prompt again is that users have to "Reset Permission" on their browsers.

[image]